# Por que tenho que usar FormData para enviar arquivos via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, formdata

Criei uma página HTML com um formulário, e nele um `imput file` e um outro campo `hidden`, todos eles com o atributo `name`.

```
<form id="meuForm" action="..." method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="1" />
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" accept=".csv" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Ao tentar receber os valores como parâmetros em minha `Action` não obtive sucesso com o arquivo, apenas com o outro campo `hidden`. Tentei então obter o arquivo através do `Request`, mas mais uma vez não obtive sucesso.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(int itemId, HttpPostedFileBase arquivo)
{
   // Forma alternativa
   var arquivoTeste = Request.Files["arquivo"];
}
```

Para enviar o formulário tentei então utilizar o `Ajax.BeginForm`, mas depois de várias tentativas desisti.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "MeuController", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "ExibeRetorno",
    OnBegin = "IniciaLoad",
    OnFailure = "alert('Deu pau!')",
    OnComplete = "FinalizaLoad();"
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="1" />
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" accept=".csv" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />

}
```

Montei todo o `ajax` via JavaScript, mas nada funcionou.

```
<form id="meuForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId" value="1" />
  <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" accept=".csv" required />
  <input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<script>
   (function(){
       $("#enviar").click(function(){
           var _itemId = $("#itemId).val();
           var _arquivo = $("#arquivo").get(0).files[0];

           $.ajax({
              beforeSend: function () {
                  IniciaLoad();
              },
              complete: function () {
                  FinalizaLoad();
              },
              contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              type: "POST",
              url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "MeuController"})',
              data: JSON.stringify({
                    itemId: _itemId,
                    arquivo: _arquivo
              }),
              success: function (data) {

              },
              fail: function () {

               },
               error: function () {

               }
          });


       });

   })();
</script>
```

Depois de várias pesquisas eu encontrei como alternativa usar o [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData), e obtive sucesso!

Em meu ajax (ultimo exemplo dado), fiz as seguintes mudanças:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("arquivo", _arquivo);
formData.append("itemId", _itemId);


$.ajax({
       ...
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       data: formData,
       ...
});
```

Mas não encontrei uma resposta detalhada do motivo pelo qual eu não conseguia enviar o arquivo pelos métodos citados anteriormente, mas somente com `FormData`.

> **1** - Por que os métodos citados não funcionaram?
>
> **2** - O que o FormData tem de diferente que faz com que funcione?

Comment: Coloque o código na sua pergunta, senão como saberemos onde está o erro?

Comment: Pergunta editada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei pesquisando mais e encontrei o motivo.

Existe um atributo no formulário chamado **enctype**, nele é definido como os dados do formulário deverão ser codificados quando enviá-los para o servidor.

Por padrão  `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` caso nada seja especificado, e neste caso não é possível enviar arquivos para o servidor.

Para resolver isso basta especificar o valor do atributo como `multipart/form-data`, pois nesse formato de codificação é possível enviar arquivos para o servidor. E então não é necessário o ajax, mas basta fazer tudo normalmente com o submit do formulário.

Mas caso o envio esteja sendo feito diretamente no javascript com ajax (ele usa como padrão o mesmo tipo de codificação), então basta usar a interface `FormData` referenciada na pergunta.

[Fonte1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)